# "They’re just kids, so treat them as." — grammatical?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality

I stumbled upon this sentence on Quora.

> They’re just kids, so treat them as.

I understand what it means but don't know how its grammatical construction works. Shouldn't the sentence be like this?:

> They're just kids, so treat them as **such**.

(Admittedly, the original sounds better in a way.)

Comment: Yes, it should but please note that we do not do corrections here.

Comment: Could be They’re just kids, so treat them as _kids [omitted]_.

Comment: Hello Detaroit, and welcome to ELL. Questions like, "Is this correct?" are off-topic on this site. You're a relative newcomer, and I can see that you're really asking about the structure with "as" in this context, so I won't vote to close. Please structure all your questions around an aspect of learning English. Also, if it's from an unreliable source like a random user on Quora, you're probably right unless you've found the same structure in many different places.

Comment: @gotube Thank you very much for your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sentence to be complete and grammatically correct, it should be, "... so treat them as kids" or "so treat them as such" (or perhaps some other similar wording.

The meaning is fairly obvious without the last word, so it would be okay for song lyrics or poetry or a slogan or headline. But it's not really correct.